# Why 2a0++ equals 2a1, BUT 2e0++ equals 3?

Tags: php

Code:

```
$a = "2c0";

for($i = 0; $i < 25; $i++) {
   print "$a ";
   $a++;
}
```

Output:

> 2c0
>   2c1
>   2c2
>   2c3
>   2c4
>   2c5
>   2c6
>   2c7
>   2c8
>   2c9
>   2d0
>   2d1
>   2d2
>   2d3
>   2d4
>   2d5
>   2d6
>   2d7
>   2d8
>   2d9
>   2e0
>   3
>   4
>   5
>   6

Why, php?

Comment: There's a very good `/r/lolphp` thread explaining this [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/lolphp/comments/1ofw7t/2d9/)

Comment: `2e0` is scientific notation for `2`. So `2 + 1 = 3`. You should really consider not mixing data types!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`2e0` is interpreted as `2 * 10^0` (see [PHP exponentiation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exp.php)) which is 2. The next value would therefore be 3.

Answer (score 1):

From the manual:

> PHP follows Perl's convention when dealing with arithmetic operations on character variables and not C's. For example, in PHP and Perl $a = 'Z'; $a++; turns $a into 'AA', while in C a = 'Z'; a++; turns a into '[' (ASCII value of 'Z' is 90, ASCII value of '[' is 91). Note that character variables can be incremented but not decremented and even so only plain ASCII alphabets and digits (a-z, A-Z and 0-9) are supported. Incrementing/decrementing other character variables has no effect, the original string is unchanged.

Using the `++` operator on "2c0" causes PHP to increment the string value, thus "2c1".  "2e0" is treated as scientific notation, i.e., `2 * 10^0 = 2`, so incrementing that gives `3`.

Answer (score 0):

See this blog post: http://blog.rstack.cc/post/2a0_misunderstanding - it explains the problem and links the php docs for reference.